# Part of string is UTF8 encoded, can't decode

Tags: python, parsing, encoding, codec

I'm parsing a file where there's some utf8 encoded text along with normal text like -

```
str = "Name: \xE1\x83\x92\xE1\x83\x90\xE1\x83\x9B\xE1\x83\x90\xE1\x83\xA0\xE1\x83\xAF\xE1\x83\x9D\xE1\x83\x91\xE1\x83\x90"
```

I'm already opening the file with utf8 encoding `open("TEXT.txt", "r", encoding="utf8")`

I expect the print(str) result to be `Name: გამარჯობა`

I've already tried encoding and decoding again and it gave me weird results as expected. Also, I couldn't purely decode it with `str.decode()` because apparently it's already decoded.

Comment: What is "normal" text? Which encoding?

Comment: It's in unicode

Answer (score 1):

The string can be converted to the expected value by encoding as 'latin-1' to get bytes, and then decoding as UTF-8:

```
>>> s = "Name: \xE1\x83\x92\xE1\x83\x90\xE1\x83\x9B\xE1\x83\x90\xE1\x83\xA0\xE1\x83\xAF\xE1\x83\x9D\xE1\x83\x91\xE1\x83\x90"
>>> s.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
'Name: გამარჯობა'
```

If you are using Python2, the string in the question is the repr of the expected string

```
>>> s = 'Name: გამარჯობა'
>>> s
'Name: \xe1\x83\x92\xe1\x83\x90\xe1\x83\x9b\xe1\x83\x90\xe1\x83\xa0\xe1\x83\xaf\xe1\x83\x9d\xe1\x83\x91\xe1\x83\x90'
```

And it can be decoded directly to unicode from UTF-8 (assuming UTF-8 is the default encoding for the Python 2 interpreter):

```
>>> s = "Name: \xE1\x83\x92\xE1\x83\x90\xE1\x83\x9B\xE1\x83\x90\xE1\x83\xA0\xE1\x83\xAF\xE1\x83\x9D\xE1\x83\x91\xE1\x83\x90"
>>> s.decode('utf-8')
u'Name: \u10d2\u10d0\u10db\u10d0\u10e0\u10ef\u10dd\u10d1\u10d0'
>>> print s.decode('utf-8')
Name: გამარჯობა
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed reply, I've tried the first method (encoding and then decoding) and instead I get funny characters like " Ã, Ã, ¢ and square blocks". I'm using python 3 which doesn't allow decoding a string like that (as it's already "decoded")

Comment: @Zuss  Can you edit your question to show the raw bytes from the file?